# How can I reference data from Firebase collections in other collections?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm building an app that involves groups and profiles.
Each profile document has information like usernames, profile pictures and follower counts stored under a document "userID"
Each group needs to be able to reference those profile documents by their userID.
How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just store a field in each group that contains the ID of the document of the profile you want to reference.  You can then query the profile document after you get a group document to work with.